# Find one entry within many and edit

Tags: symfony, controller, symfony-3.4

**[SETTINGS]**

- Symfony 3.4
- `Box` entity: ['id', 'name']
- `Item` entity ['id', 'name', 'type']

  - `type`: enum:: *toy, card, candy*
- `BoxItem` entity: ['id', 'box_id', 'item_id']

  - Each `Box` always have one `item` whose `type` is *toy*
  - Each `Box` always have one `item` whose `type` is *card*
  - Each `Box` can have zero or more (0,n) `item` whose `type` is *candy*

**[PROBLEM & FILES]**

I have a `OneToMany <=> ManyToOne` relation between my three entities, `BoxItem` being the middle one.
When I persist a `Box`, some default values are persisted into `BoxItem`.

My problem is when I want to edit the data in `BoxItem`, I can't figure out how to fetch the data I need.

What I need is an `editAction()`, which we will call `toyAction()` to edit the current pre-selected toy, and another one to edit the pre-selected card.
Candies are simply added or deleted.

Can someone give me an example of how I would need to write `toyAction()` so I can fetch the only associated `item['toy]' and change it?

This is my current `toyAction()`

<kbd>**BoxItemController**</kbd>

```
/**
 * @Route("boxitem-toy-{boxId}", name="boxitem_toy")
 * @ParamConverter("boxItem", options={"box"="boxId"})
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param BoxItem $boxItem
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function toyAction(Request $request, BoxItem $boxItem) {
    $editForm=$this->createForm(BoxItemToyType::class, $boxItem);
    if($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        if($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

            return $this->json(array('submit_status'=>true));
        } else {
            return $this->json(array('submit_status'=>false));
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('boxitem/toy.html.twig', array(
            'boxItem'=>$boxItem,
            'edit_form'=>$editForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

There are at least two problems with the current code.

First, in the `@ParamConverter` annotation, `box` isn't recognized. I'm guessing the reason is that `box` attribute is a `OneToMany <=> ManyToOne` relation, and thus I'm not using the correct syntax. I tried `box_id` instead, but I still get the same error.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Invalid option(s) passed to @ParamConverter: box").

Second, as it's, I'm looking for every entry with the right `box_id`, I need to extend the search and join `Item` to get the only entry whose `type` attribute will be set to *toy* and return one entry or null.

Comment: If Box always have one type of Item with type Toy, wouldn't it be better to have three associations? One for Toy, one for Card and one for rest of items? Would be then easier in code.

Comment: @M.Kebza It would be indeed, but I simplified the code here, there are some constrains that prevent me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we keep your associations (with comment up) I would approach it like this.

```
 /**
 * @Route("boxitem-toy-{box}", name="boxitem_toy")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
 public function toyAction(Request $request, Box $box) {
    $toyBoxItem = null;
    foreach ($box->getItems() as $item) { // Iterate though all items
        if ($item->getType() == 'Card') { // Your check if this is card item... 
            $toyBoxItem = $item;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($toyBoxItem == null) {
        throw new NotFoundException(); // We dont have item
    }

    // ... rest of your code
}
```

To explain it. Because we have Box as parameter and we are loading it by id, then we don't need ParamConverted, it should find it.

Next we need to get ToyItem (I wrote it here in function but actually its good idea to move that code to Entity / Service - something like `$box->getToyItem()` ...).

Next as parameter of this you don't get the BoxItem, but associated entity Box from which you get your entity. Similiar will be for cardAction.